# Error en cURL json: No se puede convertir tipo de datos de String a Collections

Tags: json, curl

estoy probando un comando

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4242/create-payment-intent -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'
```

y me aparece esto:

> Invoke-WebRequest : No se puede enlazar el parámetro 'Headers'. No se puede convertir el valor "Content-Type: application/json" de tipo "System.String" al tipo "System.Collections.IDictionary".
> En línea: 1 Carácter: 61

y probando con un segundo comando tampoco resulto

```
    curl -H POST http://localhost:4242/create-payment-intent -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'
```

literal me aparecio lo mismo que cuando use el -x

```
>Invoke-WebRequest : No se puede enlazar el parámetro 'Headers'. No se puede convertir el valor "Content-Type: application/json" de tipo "System.String" al tipo "System.Collections.IDictionary".
```

En línea: 1 Carácter: 61

Comment: que optienes si entras a esta URL desde tu navegador: http://localhost:4242/create-payment-intent ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El comando esta mal formado debería ser:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4242/create-payment-intent
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -d '{"login":"my_login","password":"my_password"}'
```

Respuesta relacionada del sitio en ingles:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977950/curl-h-or-curl-header-not-working

Pruebas realizadas en: https://reqbin.com/req/c-dwjszac0/curl-post-json-example

Comment: esas letras que tiene un signo de menos al principio que significan?

Comment: son los nombre de los parámetros de forma asociativa; -H significa que es un parámetro del header... el cual usa para armar internamente el request...

Comment: pues esta raro ya que en el tutorial le funciona bien con el -x checa este link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WG4ehXSEpz4&t=171s  ya esta en el minuto correcto solo pon pausa y veras que pone el -X

Comment: tu lo estas haciendo en mac ???

Comment: hay diferencias entre versiones y sistema operativo...

Comment: lo estoy corriendo en windows

Comment: entonces no es la misma version de curl; aunque en el video no salga si te fijas las ventanas tienen el layu¿out de mac... no confio en lo que se hace en mac por que suelen tener tecnologias propietarias y no quiero pensar que ese argumento -X es especifico de la version de curl que corre en mac XD

Comment: de hecho tiene sentido aun que si te fijas bien ahorita que lo mencionas en la ventana hasta arriba después del nombre del proyecto dice zsh, cheque así de a rápido que es y resulta que es un sistema de ventana de comandos tipo PowerShell pero para sistemas Linux, aun que yo no dudo que el programa venga también para mac :/ de todos modos muchas gracias por aclarar mi duda :)

Comment: @ulisesalvarez de nada para eso estamos!

Comment: jajajaj ya lo cheque y lo volvi a checar y ni cambiando la x por la h funciona, me sigue apareciendo el mismo mensaje de invoke web request :(

Comment: @ulisesalvarez entonces algo anda mal en tu sitio, por que yo hice las pruebas y acabo de actualizar esta respuesta y funciona bien ... incluso ahora le agregue la -X

Comment: actualizar el post se hace con el comando npm?

Comment: @ulisesalvarez disculpa queria decir que actualice el contenido de esta respuesta...

Comment: listo ya lo actualice a como estoy ahorita

Comment: probaste lo que te comente en tu post???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45183355/invoke-webrequest-cannot-bind-parameter-headers/48521023

Comment: como te digo lo intente pero me arrojaba el mismo error :/ lo que si no e probado es si actualizando el curl me quita el error

Comment: no revisa el link que te acabo de pasar esta relacionado al error ...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131352/discussion-between-arcanis-the-omnipotent-and-ulises-alvarez).

Answer (score 0):

yo finalmente lo logré de la siguiente manera:
post:
curl.exe -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"task":"5"}' http://localhost:5000/

es decir colocando una barra invertida antes de comilla doble para el diccionario

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]